# Auto Adding from Google Chrome to macOS Notes

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notes.app

How do I make it possible to add stuff (text, links, images) from Google Chrome to macOS Notes app?

(It's available on right click or through extension to Evernote, Milanote, and so on, but not for the built-in Apple's Notes app)

Tried creating a service but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my rough service workflow: 
[image: Automator workflow]

Only texts can be added, and a new note is created. 
Apple Script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "System Events"

        tell process "Notes"

            click menu item "New Note" of menu "File" of menu bar 1
            click menu item "Paste" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1

        end tell

     end tell
     return input
end run
```

**Update*2:**
To add pictures, simply use another Apple Script block that clicks a menu item. And add some delay for Notes app to launch. 
[image: Updated workflow]

```
on run {input, parameters}

    tell application "System Events"

        tell process "Google Chrome"

            click menu item "Copy" of menu "Edit" of menu bar 1

        end tell

     end tell
     return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to add text directly to Notes through the context menu.